# How do I create a shortcut for a HTML 5 app via chrome?

Tags: html, google-chrome

I have a HTML 5 app which works with offline storage.  It only needs to work in Chrome at the moment.  I want the user to be able to access the app both online and offline.  At the moment I am asking the user to bookmark the page to come back to it when offline.

I would like to have a link: "Click here to create a desktop shortcut".  Does anybody know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I encourage you to get your app in the [Chrome Web Store](http://chrome.google.com/webstore) and it will be installed to the users Chrome.  Any app that is created to work offline will work offline regardless of it having a desktop icon or not.

If the user is on Windows they can also create an application shortcut that will be placed on to the desktop.